# Display results of SQL query in AngularJS when using $ctrl instead of $scope

Tags: html, angularjs

So I have a problem displaying result of SQL query in AngularJS.

PHP file works perfectly

**Template**

```
<table id="penetration">
   <tr>
       <th>Penetration Pipe 33.1</th>
       <th>Penetration Pipe 33.2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>TT0101: <span class="value"></span><br/>
           TT0102: <br/>
            {{ $ctrl.TT0101Value }}
            TT0103: </td>
       <td>TT0107: </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Component**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('cryostat', []).component('cryostat', {
    templateUrl: 'cryostat/cryostat.template.html',
    controller: function cryostatController($scope, $http, $q) {
        this.pageTitle = "NP04 Cryostat"
        this.natalie = 1;
        var temp1 = $http.get("cryostat/cryostat.conn.php");
        var temp2 = $http.get("cryostat/cryostat.conn.php");
        $q.all([temp1, temp2]).then(function (resultArray) {
            cryostatController.TT0101 = resultArray[0].data.records;
            cryostatController.TT0101Value = cryostatController.TT0101[0].Mnish;
            console.log(cryostatController.TT0101Value);
            console.log(cryostatController.TT0101[0].Mnish);
            // this.TT0102 = resultArray[1];
    });
    this.httpresult = $http.get("cryostat/cryostat.conn.php")
        .then(function (response) {cryostatController.resss = response.data.records;});
}
});
```

The problem is that it's empty, i.e. doesn't display anything, tried also using this.TT0101 but this throws error undefined

What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you not using `$scope`? You are injecting into your controller. Might as well use it.

Comment: I followed the AngularJS tutorial on their website that recommended this way for multipage applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that. Found an answer myself.

Replaced **cryostatController** with **self** and added **var self = this;**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('cryostat', []).component('cryostat', {
    templateUrl: 'cryostat/cryostat.template.html',
    controller: function cryostatController($scope, $http, $q) {
        this.pageTitle = "NP04 Cryostat"
        this.natalie = 1;
        var self = this;
        var temp1 = $http.get("cryostat/cryostat.conn.php");
        var temp2 = $http.get("cryostat/cryostat.conn.php");
        $q.all([temp1, temp2]).then(function (resultArray) {
            self.TT0101 = resultArray[0].data.records;
            // this.TT0102 = resultArray[1];
    });
}
});
```